# modal no responde al submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

tengo el problema siempe al principio que empiezo a crear una modal al enviar los datos , la anterior ocasion cambie jquery y funciono, pero ahora copio y pego el codigo de una modal que si funciona llamandola con jquery.

hice la modal con el menor codigo posible para que sea mas facil de leer

el problema es que cuando le presiono al botton de agregar no funciona submit ni los console.log imprime

```
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form id="formularioAgregar" role="form">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Agregar un celular</b></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label class="control-label">Nombre de perfil</label>
          <input type="text" name="Datos[nombrePerfil]" id="nombrePerfil" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="agregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




js


var contar = [], dias = [], diasSemana = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"];
$(function () {
    variable = $("#div_alert");
 // alert(variable);
    $("#tblPerfiles").DataTable();
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow"); 
    if (typeof variable !== 'undefined' && variable !== null) {
        // setTimeout(function(){cerrar("div_alert");}, 3000);
    }

});

$( "#formularioAgregar" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    console.log('asasasa');
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});

function agregar(){
    dias = [];
    $.ajax({
        url:   'index.php?accion=alta',
            type:  'post',
        success:  function (data) {
            $("#modalPerfil").html(data);
            $(".timepicker").timepicker({ showInputs: false, showMeridian: false});
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({style: 'btn-success btn-sm',size: 4,noneSelectedText: 'Seleccionar un elemento', liveSearchPlaceholder:'Buscar',noneResultsText: '¡No existe el elemento buscado!',countSelectedText:'{0} elementos seleccionados',actionsBox:true,selectAllText: 'Seleccionar todos',deselectAllText: 'Deseleccionar todos'});
            $('#formAgregar').validator({focus:false});
        },
    });
    $("#modalPerfil").modal("show");
}

function agregarFila(){
    if ($('#diasTrabajados option:selected')=="") {
        $('#entrada').hide();
        $('#salida').hide();
        $("#diasTrabajados").hide();        
    }else{
        $('#entrada').show();
        $('#salida').show();
        $("#telefonoExtension").attr("required","required");
    }
    diasTmp = [], opciones = "";
    $('#diasTrabajados option:selected').each(function(i, obj) {
        //concatena dias y this
        dias.push($(this).val());
    });
    //elimina nodos duplicados

    $.grep(diasSemana, function(el) {
        if ($.inArray(el, dias) == -1) diasTmp.push(el);
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < diasTmp.length; i++){
        opciones += "<option>" + diasTmp[i] + "</option> ";  
    }
    cajita = '<div class="form-group col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><label>Horarios</label><input type="text" name="horarioEntrada" class="form-control " value="'+$('#entrada').val()+'" readonly></div></div>'; 
    cajita += '<div class="form-group col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><label></label><input type="text" name="horarioSalida" class="form-control" value="'+$('#entrada').val()+'" readonly></div></div>';
    cajita += '<div class="form-group col-md-5"><label class="control-label">Dias trabajados</label><input type="hidden" name="diasTrabajados2" required>'+$('#diasTrabajados').val()+'</div>';
    cajita += '<div class="form-group col-md-1"><a><i class="fa fa-minus eliminarFila" style="cursor:pointer" agregarFila()  onclick="eliminarHorario(this,\''+$('#diasTrabajados').val()+'\');" ></i></a></div>';
    cuadro = '<div class="form-group col-md-11 horarios">'+cajita+'</div>';
    $("#prueba").append(cuadro);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({style: 'btn-success btn-sm',size: 4,noneSelectedText: 'Seleccionar un elemento', liveSearchPlaceholder:'Buscar',noneResultsText: '¡No existe el elemento buscado!',countSelectedText:'{0} elementos seleccionados',actionsBox:true,selectAllText: 'Seleccionar todos',deselectAllText: 'Deseleccionar todos'});        
    $(".timepicker").timepicker({ showInputs: false });
    // console.log(dias);
    $("#diasTrabajados").html(opciones);
    $("#diasTrabajados").selectpicker("refresh");
}

function eliminarHorario(elemento, diasTmp){
    opciones = "";
    $(".loader").fadeIn("fast", function(){
        diasTmp = diasTmp.split(",");
        for(var i = 0; i < diasTmp.length; i++){
            index = dias.indexOf(diasTmp[i]);
            console.log(index);
            if (index > -1) {
                dias.splice(index, 1);
            }
            opciones += "<option>" + diasTmp[i] + "</option>";  
        }
        $("#diasTrabajados").append(opciones);
        $("#diasTrabajados").selectpicker("refresh");
        $(elemento).closest('div.horarios').remove();  
        $(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
    });
}

function modificar(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:   'index.php?accion=modificar&id='+id,
            type:  'post',
        success:  function (data) {
            $("#modalSalario").html(data);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({style: 'btn-success btn-sm',size: 4,noneSelectedText: 'Seleccionar un elemento', liveSearchPlaceholder:'Buscar',noneResultsText: '¡No existe el elemento buscado!',countSelectedText:'{0} elementos seleccionados',actionsBox:true,selectAllText: 'Seleccionar todos',deselectAllText: 'Deseleccionar todos'});
            $('#formEditar').validator({focus:false});
        },
    });
    $("#modalSalario").modal("show");
}

function eliminar(id){
    $("#modalEliminar").unbind().modal({ backdrop: "static", keyboard: false }).one("click", "#eliminar", function (e) {
        $(".loader").fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $.ajax({
                data:{id: id},
                url:   'index.php?accion=eliminar',
                type:  'post',
                success:  function (data) {
                    if(data == "OK")
                        window.location.replace("index.php?accion=index&clase=success");
                    else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                },

            });
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: No termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema. ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para que lo veamos?

Comment: no funciona el submit cuando se presiona en agregar

Comment: Tu código funciona sin problemas (como puedes ver en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86vazd74/)). Lee cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para crear una demo en la que podamos ver el error y ayudarte con el problema.

Comment: no me arroja un error simplemente no funcioan el submit me recarga la pagina y no  manda los console, no deberia recargar la pagina por event.preventDefault();

Comment: Comprendo, pero si no compartes el código mínimo para reproducir el problema, nosotros no podemos ayudarte. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y crea un demo en tu propia pregunta.

Comment: ahi estan los 3 archivos que estoy ocupando no creo que sea necesario el controlador ya que no llegan al js.  al darle en agregar en la vista principal me abre la modal que trae un input de texto (nombre de perfil) y de ahi es donde no me hace nada al darle en guardar no deberia recargar la pagina e imprimir console.log()

Answer (score 0):

ya tengo la respuesta :D

```
    $(document).on("submit", "#formularioAgregar", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("asdasdasdasds");
});
```

como es una modal que no existe al cargar el documento se tiene que usar (document).on para estos tipos de casos.

(cuando exista submit con el id formularioAgregar has esto ....)

las otra funcion  en el codigo no es que este mal solo que no aplica por que ya se leyo el documento y mi modal se llena cuando se le manda se solicita se llena por medio de una pagina alta.php me trae la moda de alta.